# Em Font Sizes not Scaling Up in iOS

Tags: ios, css, font-size

I have done this properly in the past but something on this new site I'm building is not properly kicking in.

My problem is that when the site is viewed in iPhone (5, which is what I have available to test) portrait mode, the font sizes are staying really small. They are not enlarging relative to the em sizes. It works properly when I squeeze my desktop browser (example below, left) but on the iPhone the type stays small.

Live site: http://debbiemillman.com/designmatters/totest/index.html

Live CSS: http://debbiemillman.com/designmatters/totest/_css/style.css

I have my -webkit-text-size-adjust:100% in there too.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing you viewport meta tag, which you currently have as `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1080" />` to the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I think that should correct the matter; it's the normal combination of settings to use with iPhones and others.

Comment: May look better, I'm old and need big fonts.  See new WinPhone screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to consider.
You have h3 conflicts css in html.css style.css and reset.css.

reset.css line 20 specifies 100%.
 
reset.css line 70 specifies 13px.
 
html.css line 180 specifies 1.17em. 
In FireFox the prevailing is style.css line 54 specifies 2em.

Specify the CSS one time. Consider not using h3 but rather
 `<p class="headline">` 
as headlines Browser style sheet is not always that easy to override. Paragraph tags are made to be altered.
If you use an id rather than a class it will be given higher precedence and possibly more consistent across all Browsers.

Not sure why but FireFox shows reset.css being loaded twice.

Looking at the timeline waterfall, you have some font files being loaded very late and holding up Start Render.  All CSS and font files should be loaded before any JS because the Browser has to parse the JS as it is loaded and then must reset preliminary layout the whenever new CSS or fonts are loaded.

Notice lines 18-23 then right after 23 DOM Content is finally loaded.

[WebPageTest Waterfall](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150204_QS_1AEJ/1/details/)

Another curious thing is the relatively small images files take over one second to load. This is especially strange when the dta transfer rate of your server is very fast.  And the 404 errors on the jquery and script.js is not good.

```
Base Page Size: 20,029 Bytes
Transmission Speed: 11,506,849 Bytes/Sec.
Compression: 7.9X
HTML Whitespace: 37.3%
Bytes Transmitted: 2,520 Bytes
HTML Transfer Rate: 91,456,621 Bytes/Sec.
```

This is how it looks on WP 8.1. Not really, when it is actual size it is very difficult to read.  The lack of high contrast does not help.

[image: Win8.1 Phone]

[image]

Comment: I also see strange behavior between a width of 569px and 57px. At 569 all images are in a single column.  At 570 they are 3 rows and 4 columns.  Then around 550px wide 2 columns and 6 rows.  Then at about 320px it goes back to 3 rows 4 columns.

Comment: Not a mobile friendly page. Ran 3 tests here are the 3 links.  Very bad.  http://gtmetrix.com/reports/debbiemillman.com/y712mRtJ  and https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdebbiemillman.com%2Fdesignmatters%2Ftotest%2Findex.html and http://validator.w3.org/mobile/check?task=2015020500382517.mobile2&docAddr=http%3A%2F%2Fdebbiemillman.com%2Fdesignmatters%2Ftotest%2Findex.html